# AspNetUserTokens table missing when migrating from Microsoft SQL to MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to migrate an Asp Net Core application Identity from Microsoft SQL to MySql

When running the application i get the following error for missing table AspNetUserTokens:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'AspNetUserTokens' doesn't exist ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'AspNetUserTokens' doesn't exist
at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.TryAsyncContinuation(Task`1 task) in ..\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 1252
```

The original SQL database never had a table named AspNetUserTokens, why does Identity try to access it?
Do I have to create this table or can I tell Identity ignore it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your dbContext?Do you have external login?

Comment: Thanks to @XingZou comment I Have removed `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` and it solved the issue but I don't understand why there is a difference between using Microsoft SQL and MySql

Comment: I am glad that you have resolved the probelm. But It works well when I add `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` in startup using Mysql.

Comment: The project started as a .net application with mssql then was migrated to .net core and then then migrated the database to MySql, mybe something happened in between...